# How to fill color over another color on same area of imageview in android?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, paint

**I have imageview and i set "A" character for filling the colors.My actual problem is how to fill color over different color on same portion of imageview? Below is my source code for color pallet for changing diferent color on click.**

```
case  R.id.btn_color_one: {
            // do something for button 1 click

            setupDrawing();
            paint.setColor(RED);
            break;
            }
        case  R.id.btn_color_two: {
            // do something for button 1 click

            setupDrawing();
            paint.setColor(LIGHT_BLUE);
            break;
            }
```

**And this is a setupDrawing(),**

```
public void setupDrawing(){
        initializeMP();
        playsound.start();

        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of R&D i got my answer:

```
private final Paint  mPaintSrcIn   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
private final Paint  mPaintDstIn   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
private final Paint  mPaintColor   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint  mPaintEraser  = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
private final Canvas mLayerCanvas = new Canvas();

private Bitmap mInnerShape;
private Bitmap mOuterShape;
private Bitmap mLayerBitmap;

private ArrayList<DrawOp> mDrawOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();
private DrawOp mCurrentOp = new DrawOp();

private ArrayList<DrawOp> mUndoneOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();


public DrawingView(Context context)
{
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mPaintSrcIn.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    mPaintDstIn.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

    mPaintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintColor.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaintColor.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    mPaintEraser.set(mPaintColor);
    mPaintEraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    mPaintEraser.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(getResources()
        .getDisplayMetrics().density * 4, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
}

public void setShape(int inner, int outer)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
    setShape(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), inner, options),
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), outer, options));
}

public void setShape(int[] inner, int[] outer){
    for(int i=0;i<inner.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<outer.length;j++){
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
            setShape(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), inner[i], options),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), outer[j], options));
        }
    }

}

public void setShape(Bitmap inner, Bitmap outer)
{
    mInnerShape = inner;
    mOuterShape = outer;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

public void setDrawingColor(int color)
{
    mCurrentOp.reset();
    mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
    mCurrentOp.color = color;
}

public void setDrawingStroke(int stroke)
{
    mCurrentOp.reset();
    mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
    mCurrentOp.stroke = stroke;
}

public void enableEraser()
{
    mCurrentOp.reset();
    mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.ERASE;
}

public void clearDrawing()
{
    mDrawOps.clear();
    mUndoneOps.clear();
    mCurrentOp.reset();
    invalidate();
}

public void undoOperation()
{
    if(mDrawOps.size() > 0){
        DrawOp last = mDrawOps.remove(mDrawOps.size() - 1);
        mUndoneOps.add(last);
        invalidate();
    }
}

public void redoOperation()
{
    if(mUndoneOps.size() > 0){
        DrawOp redo = mUndoneOps.remove(mUndoneOps.size() - 1);
        mDrawOps.add(redo);
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mLayerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mLayerCanvas.setBitmap(mLayerBitmap);

    if(mOuterShape != null){
        int dx = (w - mOuterShape.getWidth()) / 2;
        int dy = (h - mOuterShape.getHeight()) / 2;
        mMatrix.setTranslate(dx, dy);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(isInEditMode()){
        return;
    }

    // NOTE: Without extra bitmap or layer.. but HW Acceleration does not support setMaskFilter which means
    // eraser has strong edges whilst drawing.
    // @see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported 
    /*
    canvas.drawBitmap(mOuterShape, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.saveLayer(null, mPaint, Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mInnerShape, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.saveLayer(null, mPaintSrcIn, Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapDraw, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaintDraw);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.restore();
    */

    // Clear software canvas
    mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    // Draw picture from ops
    for(DrawOp op : mDrawOps){
        drawOp(mLayerCanvas, op);
    }
    drawOp(mLayerCanvas, mCurrentOp);

    // Mask the drawing to the inner surface area of the shape
    mLayerCanvas.drawBitmap(mInnerShape, mMatrix, mPaintDstIn);

    // Draw orignal shape to view
    canvas.drawBitmap(mOuterShape, mMatrix, null);

    // Draw masked image to view
    canvas.drawBitmap(mLayerBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

private void drawOp(Canvas canvas, DrawOp op)
{
    if(op.path.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    final Paint paint;
    if(op.type == DrawOp.Type.PAINT){
        paint = mPaintColor;
        paint.setColor(op.color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
    }else{
        paint = mPaintEraser;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
    }
    mLayerCanvas.drawPath(op.path, paint);
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mUndoneOps.clear();
            mCurrentOp.path.moveTo(x, y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for(int i = 0; i < event.getHistorySize(); i++){
                mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(event.getHistoricalX(i), event.getHistoricalY(i));
            }
            mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
            mDrawOps.add(new DrawOp(mCurrentOp));
            mCurrentOp.path.reset();
            break;
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap class has a getPixel(int x, int y) that returns a Color http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html.

Then you can check the value and setPixel again to a new one. Just run all the bitmap checking for red and set it to blue or whatever.

Comment: `if (mybitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.CYAN) {mybitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.RED)}`

Comment: remember adding a for for x, another one for y and use your colors instead of mine

Comment: which value take for x,y?

Comment: i also use canvas and paint object.

Comment: Dude! just run the width and height of the bitmap (from zero). You can achieve that just by using a modifiable bitmap.

Comment: please see the image, i have color pallet(Button) for changing the color values. If user click on any button of color pallet then that color is use for filling the area of imageview. Now how can i manage it?

Comment: So, let state this: You´ve got the toon there with three areas of three colors. Users click on one area, then click on one button and you fill the area with that color?....  If so, when user clicks, you get the color to be replaced from bitmap.getPixel(x,y). and in button click, run!

Comment: wanted to vote down this question because you´re looking for someone to program the problem for you but I don´t have enough reputation to do so... darn thing!

Comment: No, there are multiple colors for filling the same area of imageview. I use canvas drawing for filling brush style color on imageview. But when i use paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER)); then i cant overlap color over color on same area of imageview. When i replace paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER/IN/OUT)); then filling color behind imageview. So i am very confuse about it. So compalsory use paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER)); but problem is not overlap color over color using that statement.